# Spring boot post write null value in db

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, postman

I've fixed the problem `Unsupported Media Type`changing the annotation `@RequestBody` with the annotation `@ModelAttribute`. Now il works, but t's sends null values at DB.

**My calss Note**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "note")
public class Note {
    
    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long idNote;
    
    private String content;
    
    private String title;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "user")
    private User user;

    public Note(){}

    public Note(Long id, String content, String title,User user ){
        this.idNote = id;
        this.content = content;
        this.title = title;
        this.user= user;
    }
```

**My class User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    
    private @Id @GeneratedValue @Column int idUser;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Note.class, mappedBy = "idNote", orphanRemoval = false, fetch = 
    FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "note")
    private Set<Note> notes;

    public User() {}

    public User(int idUser, String name, String surname, Set<Note> notes) {
        this.idUser = idUser;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.notes = notes;
    }
```

**My post method**

```
//REQUEST BODY
    @PostMapping(path="body", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    void ResponseBodyPost(@ModelAttribute Note note){
        noteService.requestBodyCU(note);
    }
```

In postman I do the request with this body:

```
{
    "content": "content8",
    "title": "title8",
    "user": 2
}
```

In DB i have only note ID value:

```
{
    "idNote": 14,
    "content": null,
    "title": null,
    "user": null
}
```

I have already set content-type to application/json. I can't understand what's my problem, there are 2 days that I'm trying to fix this.

Comment: Is `note` received properly in the method `ResponseBodyPost`? And how `noteService` saves `note` to the database?

Comment: @Marc if I do a System.out in responseBody Post, it prints null value.

Comment: Ok. In the JSON request, the user is not an integer but should be an object. And you should switch back to `@RequestBody` if you want to map the request JSON to an object.

Comment: If I use `@RequestBody` it returns me `Unsupported Media Type` error, even if I insert a result returned by postman appropriately modified

Comment: In Postman, have you selected body type `raw` and then `JSON` in the drop down menu?

Comment: just resolved by change `@JsonManagedReference(value = "user")`  whit `@jJsonBackReference` and returned tu `@RequestBody`